# How do I get screen not to mangle some UTF-8 sequences?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, unicode

I am trying to track down where my UTF-8 is getting mangled, after failing to post emoji into Irssi one too many times. I have managed to get this far:

- Local terminal, `echo` , displays correctly
- SSH into my server, `echo` , displays correctly
- Start `screen`, `echo` , pastes as question-mark-in-diamond thing, hit Enter, displays the same question-mark-in-diamond thing.

Since it happens on pasting, maybe the issue is happening getting the data *to* the server, as opposed to getting it *from* the server...

Locale on the local terminal (macOS 10.12.1 Terminal.app):

```
LANG="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Locale on the server (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS):

```
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Additional diagnostics:

- `screen -U` doesn't change things
- `:utf8 on` command from inside screen acknowledges that it has turned on UTF-8 support, but doesn't change things
- `echo 火` does print 火 as expected, so it's not like *all* UTF-8 text is broken.

Comment: For those people whose WWW browsers are, ironically, also showing replacement characters for this question, these are U+1F525 and U+706B.

Comment: Argh, so it is. I did search before posting, too.   Well, at least it has an answer. Even if it means having to do a dist-upgrade. :/